# Pulling strings from a single string and then deleting the spaces

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bar code that I need to pull specific parts from that string. It is a massive identifier code, it is 90 chars long and each position has a specific meaning, I just need to take that 90 char string and pull out as a string, chars 16-35, 35-43, and 89.

Is there a VBA function that I can use once or three times to pull each of these strings out of the original?

Also, inside of each string there are spaces where chars are not used, I would like to have those deleted out to keep each of the following strings shorter.

```
Original String = FE52I     FJKD4T52BCYT8L           LEN274H9QRR                              ME01B29BC4GPSI

I need:     
String 1 = "T52BCYT8L"   
String 2 = "LEN274H9QRR"   
String 3 = "S"
```

There is extra space as placeholders in this barcode in case there is differing length of string 1 and 2.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Consider using mid, i.e. mid(text, start position, number of characters)

Comment: For spaces see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571192/access-vba-to-trim-space-around-a-specific-character-or-wordss-in-a-column/8571442#8571442

Comment: For the final answer, why 3 string variables rather than a single array of 3 strings?

Comment: `String 2 = "LEN274H9QRR"` and you said in your question `and pull out as a string, chars 35-43` So something is wrong, because pulling out chars 35-43 would get you `LEN274H9Q` instead of `LEN274H9QRR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will extract the strings as you specified in your post, and also will remove the blank spaces:

```
Sub GET_STRINGS(ByVal ThisBarCode As String)

Dim STR_A, STR_B, STR_C As String

STR_A = Replace(Mid(ThisBarCode, 16, 20), " ", "")
STR_B = Replace(Mid(ThisBarCode, 35, 10), " ", "")
STR_C = Replace(Mid(ThisBarCode, 89, 1), " ", "")

Debug.Print STR_A
Debug.Print STR_B
Debug.Print STR_C

End Sub
```

The output you get here will be:

```
T52BCYT8L
LEN274H9Q
S
```

Please, **note the second one does not fit your example** because i followed your instructions (**pulling out chars 35-43**), so probably this code needs a little update when you know exactly what you want. But it's easy. Just set the [Mid Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/mid-function) to pull out how many chars, and that's all.

Also, **this code will work properly only if your bar code is 90 chars long, as your example.**