# Remove all letters from a string column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a migration to change a column type from string to integer.

```
def change
  change_column :emails, :object_id, :integer
end
```

This migration is failed because this column already contains string values. Before executing this migration I'm trying to remove all letters from this column so that i can get only integer values. Existing values are like

```
"AB12345"
"A12345X"
"789X26A"
```

What script i should execute before migration to remove all letters and achieve only integer values like this?

```
"12345"
"12345"
"78926"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than say 10,000 records do the conversion in the database itself. For postgres, that'd be something like:

```
select regexp_replace('1231ASDF12', '[^0-9]', '', 'g')
```

You can use `execute` to run raw sql in a migration:

```
update table set col = regexp_replace(col,  '[^0-9]', '', 'g')
```

Keep in mind if you're intending `object_id` to be a foreign key, you'll need to update whatever table is referenced and also ensure you haven't inadvertently broken anything (e.g., if there was AB123 and BC123 in the dataset).

Comment: It worked. object_id is not a foreign key. So, its safe to execute this script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the trim function but the folloing line would do just fine as well.

```
result = Replace("Some sentence containing Avenue in it.", "Avenue", "Ave")
```

Example from [Access VBA | How to replace parts of a string with another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550240/access-vba-how-to-replace-parts-of-a-string-with-another-string)

You could change "A" into ""
"B" into "" ect.

You would end up whit a code like this

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <>""
        ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, "A", "")
        ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, "B", "")
        ActiveCell.Value = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, "C", "")
        ect...
        ActiveCell.Offset (-1,0).Select
Loop
```