# How to remove each line break character within a field in vba

Tags: vba, csv

Tell me how to solve this problem? Sorry for my english. I am from Ukraine.
There is a text file in CSV format with endings of strings in unix-format.

```
List of fields:

1) ID;
2) Surname;
3) First name;
4) Middle name;
5) Date of birth;
6) Type and number of the document proving the identity;
7) Address of residence;
8) Registration address.

There are no tabs inside the field, but there is an unshielded newline character `("\ n")`.
```

The first field (ID) has a numeric type and is guaranteed not  contain a newline character.
How to write the script on vba that will remove each line break character
 inside the fields?

So that you better understand my request to help,here the example `(in xls)` wrong format
[wrong](https://www.sendspace.com/file/95g61j)
and correct
[correct](https://www.sendspace.com/file/eu1io6).

Comment: You can use Replace. Look for a blank line character. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550240/access-vba-how-to-replace-parts-of-a-string-with-another-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove Line Break in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024402/how-to-remove-line-break-in-string)

Answer (score 1):

try this macro;

```
Sub Broken_line_remover()
' Removing carriage returns from text strings

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.Cells.Replace what:=Chr(10), replacement:=" "
Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```